# SwiftUI onDrag being called twice

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing Drag & Drop using SwiftUI. The problem I'm facing is that onDrag is called twice: The first time is when long press gesture happens and the second time is after starting dragging/moving my finger (after the long press).

Also preview is displayed twice. First one on long press and the second one on actual drag. The second one looks like my view (created in `makePreviewItem(...)`). The first one is just a bit scaled item.

```
var body: some View {
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyVGrid(columns: ...) {
        ForEach(...) { item in
            createItem(...)
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.didSelect(item)
                }
                .onDrag {
                    let haptic = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
                    haptic.prepare()
                    haptic.impactOccurred()
                    draggingItem = item
                    viewModel.didStartDragging(item)
                    return NSItemProvider(object: String(item.id) as NSString)
                } preview: {
                    makePreviewItem(...)
                }
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: DropRelocateDelegate(didFinishDragging: {
                draggingItem = nil
                viewModel.didFinishDragging()
            }))
        }
    }
}
.frame(height: 100)
```

So I'd like to display my preview view (`makePreviewItem(...)`) immediately (when long press occurs) and I don't want onDrag to be called twice.

Comment: Mix of onTapGesture and onDrag has look of situation likely to cause SwiftUI problems. I'd suggest test removing onTapGesture to see if onDrag works better in its absence. Then if it does, refactor to use List and its built in selection binding mechanism (instead of the vanilla ForEact). Afraid need a minimal runnable demo for any other suggestions.

Comment: If I remove onTap gesture it's called once. However my custom Drag preview view is not rendered until I start moving my finger.
So when I ling press: Some default preview is displayed.
When I start moving my finger after a long press: My preview is displayed.
If I don't start moving my finger after a long press, onDrag is not called at all and preview is hidden after several seconds.

Comment: Not displaying the onDrag preview until dragging commences would be expected default based on how A's apps work, e.g. Files app. I expect the default Long Press Preview (LPP ) default will be rendering something based on the image registered with the system for that UTType, this case 'String`.  So to get nicer LPP creating and using own UTType with nicer associated image might worth trying.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean. When a long press or drag is initiated then the boolean is set to `true`, and each gesture checks whether the boolean is true which does not run the code, once the drag or press has been completed, the boolean returns back to `false`. This stops the drag action being initiated twice.

Comment: I have to return NSItemProvider in .onDrag {}. So boolean will not fix the problem.

Comment: No need to return a boolean, just add a `@State hasDragStarted: Bool = false` to the view. Then in your drag code check `guard hasDragStarted == false else return` to see if the drag has been started. Then obviously set it to true when it starts and false when it ends.